# div para de ser atualizada no IE11

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, internet-explorer, cache

Em um projeto que estou desenvolvendo preciso atualizar alguns campos da página a cada `50ms` (isso é ajustável). O problema é que, quando testo no IE, os campos deixam de ser atualizados de uma hora para outra, sem explicação alguma. Normalmente, funciona alguns segundos e para.

Já verifiquei o seguinte: o depurador (do IE) não acusa nada, funciona liso no Chrome e no Firefox, e as condições `(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)` são satisfeitas, `setInterval()` está funcionando. A página só volta a funcionar na base do <kbd>F5</kbd>.

O código que utilizo para atualizar os campos é o seguinte:

```
var adc_array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; 

function update_adc() 
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            adc_array = xmlhttp.responseText.split(" ");

            for (var i = 0; i < adc_array.length; i++) 
            {
                if(adc_array[i])
                {
                    document.getElementById("adc" + i).innerHTML = adc_array[i] + " V";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "./rtu:analogic_inputs", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Onde: as `div's` atualizas são adc0, adc1 ,adc2, adc3, adc4, adc5 e `./rtu:analogic_inputs` é o endereço que pego as informações que serão atualizadas (e está funcionando corretamente no IE).

---

Aparentemente é como se o `xmlhttp.open()` houvesse falhado, mas isso não está ocorrendo (posso acessar manualmente, e funciona nos outros navegadores).

Comment: Isso possivelmente ocorre porque o delay é pequeno, em especial se a aplicação perde o foco. No Gecko e no webkit, por exemplo, acho que se usar setInterval e aplicação não estiver em foco ele executa as rotinas a não menos do que 100ms ou 1000ms. Talvez esteja atingindo um limite semelhante

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Valeu pela sugestão, mas testei aqui com delays maiores e o problema permanceu.

Comment: No painel de requisições de rede das dev tools do IE aparece o quê? As requisições podem estar sendo feitas, o resultado vindo do cache, e visualmente nada muda.

Comment: O `adc_array` não é declarado com `var` portanto é uma variável global. Outras funções podem estar a interferir com essa variável.

Comment: @luiscubal Desculpe, eu esqueci de por no post. Vou editar lá. Mas acho que o problema está mais para o que o bfavaretto disse. Mas ainda não consegui resolver.

Comment: @LucasNunes Para testar essa hipótese, proponho o seguinte teste: ponha um console.log dentro do `onreadystatechanged`. Se o resultado vier da cache, então o console.log irá aparecer, mas repetido.

Comment: @luiscubal Fiz o teste do `console.log` e está como você disse. Repetindo (só no IE).

Comment: @LucasNunes Experimente juntar parâmetros GET ignorados (`./rtu:analogic_inputs?v=[int incrementado de cada vez]`) e veja se o problema continua a existir.

Comment: @luiscubal Consegui resolver o problema! Era o cache mesmo. Adicionei alguns parametros HTTP (no meu caso não há necessidade de armazenar cache mesmo) e resolveu. Use o seguinte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093112/is-there-a-way-to-make-internet-explorer-not-cache-a-particular-website.

Comment: @luiscubal Sua sugestão vira fácil uma resposta, não quer postar?

Comment: @LucasNunes A solução que você usou também poderia ser postada como resposta, com uma breve explicação. Se você e o luiscubal postarem respostas, outros usuários com o mesmo problema vão poder achar facilmente *duas* soluções :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Vou publicar uma resposta, mas nunca cheguei a ter a confirmação que a minha versão funcionava.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ok. Estava esperando o luiscubal postar, mas vou postar o que fiz também.

Comment: @luiscubal Passar um número incremental ou um timestamp na url é um dos métodos tradicionais de se evitar cache em ajax, funciona sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que o Internet Explorer está a verificar que os pedidos são repetidos e, como tal, recorre à cache.

Aparentemente, ele não faz isso das primeiras vezes, daí que demore tempo a começar a falhar.

Para resolver isso, é preciso impedir o IE de usar a cache para este pedido.
A solução do [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (`$.ajax` com `cache: false`) é usar um parâmetro GET adicional não utilizado.

> It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
>   GET parameters.

Traduzindo:

> Funciona através da adição de "_={data-hora}" no fim dos parâmetros GET.

Variar os parâmetros GET (seja assim, seja com nºs aleatórios ou com nºs sequenciais) é uma forma de evitar este problema.

Há outras formas de o fazer, por exemplo controlando os pedidos HTTP. O servidor pode enviar para o cliente (no pedido `./rtu:analogic_inputs`):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Answer (score 4):

Consegui resolver o problema. Como discutido nos comentários da pergunta, a causa do problema foi que o IE parau de requisitar as informações do servidor e começou a utilizar as informações em cache. Como resultado, dava-se a impressão que os resultados não eram mais atualizados.

Como a página que estou desenvolvendo não precisa armazenar informações em cache, resolvi o problema acrescentando alguns parâmetros HTTP nas requisições, conforme encontrei [na verão em Inglês do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1093173/1623979) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Sendo o [primeiro](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) para HTTP 1.1, e o [segundo](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.32) para navegadores antigos.
Esses três parâmetros são necessários pois alguns navegadores mais anarquistas não respeitam alguns parâmetros.

Comment: A resposta em inglês não menciona a terceira linha, e a primeira linha tem só o `no-cache`... Outra resposta em inglês sobre o assunto que pode ser útil: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1383359/32775

Comment: @luiscubal Esqueci de citar a segunda fonte, de onde tirei essas diferenças. Valeu.